# Play Store Internal Test Track, Swap to Live

Tags: android, google-play

I have a test build in my Internal Test Track, and the way it used to work, is that you'd download the live version and update to the test version. However at some point recently it seems that you can now only download the test version of the app unless you opt out, which also only seems to be possible from the play console.

I was hoping to be able to swap between the two versions. Is there something I am missing or has this functionality been removed?

Answer (score 0):

Users will always get the highest version they have available. See [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213), under "Version code requirements". So you can't download the test version from the Play Store if the production version is higher.